# 19th Century Store Shelves for These Races: Or, I don't want to have ladders in 19th Century shops

Tags: economy, fantasy-races

I'm looking for the races describes in this questions: [Rail Transportation with Races Described Below - Specifically, Seating](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/rail-transportation-with-races-described-below-specifically-seating)

These races have their solar power rail systems set up and running. With faster transportation comes better trade, leading to stores being better. I don't want to have people put ladders for the smallfolk - these would get in the way. What other methods can be used for all-inclusive store shelves for these specific races? By the way, the tallest race (Na'vi) is 10 feet tall, and the shortest (Larval Neirn) are only 2 feet tall, for specifications. Four taur races, race of sapient raptors, 3 foot tall ooze people, 2 races with wings, snake people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an 19th century style environment, shops would be small and there would be a shopkeeper or two around.  The shopkeeper would simply help customers get things off high shelves.

Alternatively, assuming the shorter races have the strength, a grabber tool could be provided to help them reach things on high shelves.  Google for "grabber tool for the handicapped" for examples.

Comment: Not a bad idea! I just Google what you said, it seems like a good idea! However, the Larval Neirn and Avandra are roughly as strong as an 8 year old human, so they could, but they would probably just ask someone for help. Thanks though!

Comment: In a 21st century environment, shops are huge and plastered with signs to *ask for assistance* with items on top shelves. Particularly in "big box" home stores, where a ladder *or even forklift* may be required to reach such items. IOW, we have this issue (and the same solution) *today*. Going back in time, stores tended to be more "full service" (customer walks up to the counter and asks the proprietor for what they need) rather than "self service" (customer collects their own items), so this answer is spot-on. Having more customers that would *need* assistance just makes it even more true.

Comment: BTW, stores run by members of the smaller races probably a) just won't stock larger items, or b) will have an employee of a larger race to help lift the big things.

Answer (score 5):

Ladders were entirely normal in 19th Century shops, more importantly, self service wasn't normal, that only came in after 1916.

All shops were all inclusive, you walked in and got service from the counter. No ladders for the customers, no shelves for the customers, no browsing. You ask for what you want and get handed it, much like many small hardware shops (in the uk) still do.

If you want to be true to your 19thC. setting and allow access to all in your shops, no self service, so no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Lay the products on the ground, rather than shelves. Check this modern rug store in Iran, most of the goods are reachable by short people:

[image: A persian rug store, most products are on the floor]

The only things not on the floor are carpets that the shopkeeper hangs on a wire.

You can lay some mats or carpets around and have the products on them. Many street markets around the world work like that.

Comment: Nice idea! This doesn't seem to hard. I might use something where an open-air market does this, and the accepted answer is for beyond the market.