# Fantasy Zootopia: Taur Races

Tags: fantasy-races, cities

Okay, for my D&D game, I'm creating a 19th Century world. I have some stuff here:

[Rail Transportation with Races Described Below - Specifically, Seating](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/rail-transportation-with-races-described-below-specifically-seating) (For Trains; Read Accepted Answer)

[19th Century Store Shelves for These Races: Or, I don't want to have ladders in 19th Century shops](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190993/19th-century-store-shelves-for-these-races-or-i-dont-want-to-have-ladders-in) (Stores: Read Accepted Answer)

My races (Described in the Rail Question) will, obviously, convalesce into a large 19th Century American city. There will HAVE to be accommodations. To us, a 12-foot ceiling is super freaking high. To the city planners of these cities, 12-foot ceilings are the main way Na'vi can stand at full height without banging their heads on the ceiling. Those too short simply hire Na'vi to help decorate. Tails and wings are also simple: Just make sure the owners aren't banging those extremities into doors by making taller doors that can also let Na'vi through. However, the Taur Races (General term for the Leonar, Ashara, Centaur, and Zavran races on the list) are too weird for me to accomodate.

**Here are some Facts about the Taur Races:**

1. They are all half humanoid, half animal. The Centaurs are horse, Ashara Dragon (Wings, reptilian body with wings, spiked tail, and upright legs), Leonar Lion. The Zavran are half anthro scorpion, half giant regular scorpion.
2. The Centaurs have one child-pregnancies (Called Singletons), Ashara have twin pregnancies (Two fraternal babies), Leonar have anywhere from twins to quadruplets, and Zavran have 3-6 eggs at a time, with 5 being most likely. Leonar cubs, Ashara wyrmlings, and Zavran hatchlings ride on their mother's back, with Zavran being generally like kids on road trips, while Ashara and Leonar generally play with each other. Leonar also groom each other. Ashara tend to goof off.
3. Their animal bodies are 4 feet (Zavran, without the tail due to said tail curving to the back) to 10 feet long (Ashara with tail), with Centaurs being 5 feet and Leonar being 6 feet with a 2 foot tail, for a total of 8 feet long.

So, my question is: ***How would a late 19th Century American city with Solar Panels accommodate the Taur Races?***

Comment: "Those too short simply hire Na'vi to help decorate." Alternatively, you don't see many decorations above six feet, and/or (step)ladders are much more popular.

Comment: Wider sidewalks

Comment: You mention solar panels precisely once, why are they relevant?

Comment: It's just that I want people to know that there is some more advanced tech in this world.

Comment: If it's significant you should specify everything, if it's not significant, best not to mention it. Otherwise you end up confusing the matter with irrelevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model it on Charleston not New York**

To me the fundamental issue with your civilization is fungibility. Equipment made for one species - if standardized at scale - will not work for other species. Zootoopia side-steps this issue in the movie by essentially segregating it's population in their living environments + forcing all creatures to walk bipedally. Judy is far from being the smallest creature in the city, but is such an anomaly because traditionally large creatures have dominated the Police Force. This is an easy solution, but doesn't seem in line with what you want.

Therefore a city that is dependent on fungibility - like New York - where a tenanted apartment occupied by one renter of size N can be reasonably occupied by another - doesn't work. You need to allow buildings to be built with flexibility in mind, so I'd look at the Row Houses of Charleston  (or any other Southern, agricultural hub). These are wide and large enough that that can be scaled up/down by adding/removing walls. Poor individuals usually live in shacks which can be built to accommodate their size on the outskirts of town, not in slums near the center.