# Fantasy Zootopia - Races with both WIngs and Tails

Tags: fantasy-races, cities

A Continuation of this: [Fantasy Zootopia: Taur Races](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/191159/fantasy-zootopia-taur-races?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I want some idea on how the Pterians and Drava (From this: [Rail Transportation with Races Described Below - Specifically, Seating](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/rail-transportation-with-races-described-below-specifically-seating?noredirect=1&lq=1)) would be accommodated. They're both above 6 feet, with Pterians being both shorter and taller than Drava; Basically, they have a wider height range than Drava. They're shorter than the tallest races, but still pretty tall. They also have wings. Pterians have 6 to 7 foot long tails, and Drava have 1 1/2 to 2 foot long tails. Both tails are moderately flexible, but I still have trouble figuring them out. I'm pretty sure there would have to be perches for them to land on while flying on roofs and stuff, but can y'all help me with this?

Comment: Both races are too large for the passenger density required to make rail travel cost effective, either they fit themselves into the available seating/standing space or they don't travel.

Comment: The trains simply have seats perpendicular to the rails. The trains are also wider, making  for extra space for wings.

Comment: Can they fold their wings neatly behind them?

Comment: @elemtilas Yes, they can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few considerations:

- Wider trains. You've got this one already, but I think it's an important point to reinforce. You could posit both wider tracks, [broad gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Western_Railway), as well as significantly wider waggons. A (comparatively) narrow gauge rail car, such as you'd find in the US, is about 10 feet wide on a 4' 10.5" gauge track.  A proper broad gauge train could have waggons easily 15 foot wide or a bit more. Plenty of space for wings and tails!
- Split bench seating: I'm going to hazard the guess that your peoples' tails are **aesthetically correct, yet anatomically incorrect** in typical fantasy mode. If their tails are at all mobile a/o prehensile, then a horizontal space between the bench seat and the back rest will be a welcome place to stick one's tail while seated. A specially constructed box behind the seat would keep the tails interacting with the feet of the passenger sitting behind. A rounded cut-out towards the back of the bench seat would provide some extra comfort as well.
- Low back seating: A relatively low profile bench back will allow winged passengers to sit relatively comfortably while riding. If their wings are "angel wings", then they'll have no trouble as the lowered backrest won't impinge upon their scapuloalar joints. They can even hook their wings over the back rest if they wish. Folks with full body width "bat wings" (wings whose tissues extend all the way down the flanks and possibly onto the legs) won't be able to do that, but should be able to sit comfortably otherwise with their wings draped along either side of their body.
- Longer benches: Goes without saying: winged folk need more space! Couples and close friends may not mind sitting close, intermingling their wings, but total strangers may not be so inclined! You might be able to cram two winged folk onto a single bench. Modern European rail carriages have an aisle width of about 22 inches, which would leave you 7 1/2 feet on each side for bench seating.
- Longitudinal benches: You could also consider having four longitudinal benches. Typical restaurant banquettes are about 27 to 30 inches deep. There is plenty of space for four longitudinal benches plus two aisleways in a 15 foot wide carriage!