# Fantasy Zootopia: Ooze People

Tags: fantasy-races, cities

My world: [Rail Transportation with Races Described Below - Specifically, Seating](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/rail-transportation-with-races-described-below-specifically-seating)

Most of the races have been accommodated now. Anything the Taurs need (Adjustable seats, wider sidewalks) accommodate the Mitarn (My Raptor Race), my super tall races (Like the Na'vi) can be accommodated by simply making super fricking high ceilings. Everyone else is automatically accommodated with height.

However, my single race that is the odd one out, the Avandra, are a tad confusing.

**Here are some basic facts about Avandra:**

1. 2 to 3 feet tall.
2. Ooze people, able to squeeze into 1 inch spaces easily.
3. Able to jump up to 5 feet upwards, and up to 10 feet horizontally.
4. Not acidic enough to be harmful to others, but acidic enough to make anything they slide over/get on  or in their bodies an acid bath, melt hair, and completely dissolve any food material, but not living material.
5. They eat food by "swallowing" it (Simply putting it into their mouth, then closing their mouth) and simply dissolving it.
6. They reproduce by fusing 2 willing Avandra into a single, inseparable blob for anywhere from 2 to 12 hours, whereupon both participants gain a discolored blob which, over the course of 7 days, develops then falls off to form a baby Avandra for both participants. This is not erotic at all, as they don't feel sexual pleasure. They only do so for reproduction.
7. They can swim well, and can climb great, going straight up walls and even going on ceilings, cleaning them as they go.
8. People can get their feet/hooves/claws/tails stuck in Avandra, sort of like how people get stuck by a gum wad on the street. Not only is this annoying for the person stuck, it's painful for the Avandra, as it's basically their equivalent of a human getting a huge nail stuck in them, but they don't get killed from it.

So, ***How would Avandra become accommodated in a 19th Century American Big City Environment?***

Comment: Being strong enough to melt food (eg meat) certainly sounds harmful to others. Most people are made of meat.

Comment: I would suggest/encourage that they instead are more like [carbosilicate amorphs](https://www.ovalkwiki.com/index.php/Carbosilicate_Amorph). To wit, their outer membrane doesn't allow acid through, and they have some conscious control over it. Not leaving a trail of corrosive slime everywhere they go will *greatly* simplify things.

Comment: @Matthew it's more like they melt stuff they come into direct contact with something. Metal, wood, and living organic material can't get melted, it's more like an acid bath.

Comment: Is there a magic factor involved? If they can melt hair on contact, there is no chemical way they will leave living humans intact. humans and 'foodstuff' are chemically identical.

Comment: @bukwyrm Yes, a slight magical factor is involved. They can ONLY digest dead things, and even then only when the thing being digested is almost totally surrounded by the ooze body completely. A living limb could survive, but the hair will be singed off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tubes.**

This is a very broad question so I will only answer concerning transportation.

There is a system of tubes throughout the city so the ooze people can move around without melting everyone else's shoes.

The tubes next to the sidewalk are uncovered (more like small aquaducts than pipes).

In dense city areas some of the tubes go underground or up the sides of buildings to avoid traffic.

For public transport there is a layer of copper on the roof for the ooze people to use. This has to be hosed down sometimes unless it rains. There are tubes from the roof to inside the car so you can for example extend a mouth into the car to talk to your friends inside without touching the floor.

In interior places there are tubes set up so the oozes can move from one room to another without moving the carpet.

Of course the standard racist slur is something about how tubes are also used to carry faecal matter (see poopoo-head).

Answer (score 0):

Edges and railings

Everybody is dangerous, in their own way, but mostly people want to get along - so usually cities are not strewn with baseball bats and throwable stones to keep the vicitmization by chance rage or foolishness low, but we  do not encase everyone in a box just because kicking can be very harmful.

Thus for the ooze people: Dividers and railings are more common than in non-ooze populated cities, because they allow the oozies to keep themselves from accidentally bumping into peole. Similarly, on walkways there are wider spots to simplify overtaking, Knobs and levers on stuff open to the public are not made from ivory or other dissolvables. Oozie-only buildings have ornate grates as entryways that they can ooze through (real gates for deliveries too, but those are usually barred), while people that would like to dissuade that mode of entry have two adjacent nets made from metals with very dissimilar electronegativity set up everywhere someone might seek to flow through - that oozie will generate their own potent battery while oozing by, quickly repelling them.

Police and emergency services have thin gloves that protect them for friendly contact, and batons and other more adversarial implements also have the bimetal add-ons that make them anathema to the pH-challenged.