# 21st Century Intracity Train Design with These Races

Tags: fantasy-races, transportation, urban-fantasy

Link To Races: [Rail Transportation with Races Described Below - Specifically, Seating](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/rail-transportation-with-races-described-below-specifically-seating)

However, this will be for my intercity and international, trains. Intercity means this: It starts in one city in stops in another. International means between countries. It will also be in the 21st Century, so actual solar panels are available. However, these trains will be underground, power supplied by electricity power lines from elsewhere.

I want a different design, still accommodating yet made for 21st Century big cities, like New York City, London, Tokyo, and Beijing. The trains, on a system called Intracity, will only supply a single city, though possible outer city parts will be possible (Outer city being just outside the main city area).

***Here are the Task an Intracity Rail System in these cities must be up to:***

1. Hold large numbers of people at a time.
2. Accommodate wings, taurs, people the size of small children, people nearly twice as tall as humans, tails, and actual raptors.
3. Be able to fit underground.
4. May be triple or even quadruple rowed, but everyone must be able to know what stop they're at.

***How would these Trains be Designed?***

Comment: The term is species*

Comment: everything you listed can fit in normal train cars.

Comment: Have you seen Disney 3D animated film, Zootopia? You can photoshop the animals with yours and off you go ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Design for the biggest and second biggest side by side, then divide the remaining space.

I've categorized the people into 3 groups. Big, Human, and Small. And given them 3 different seat configurations.

I haven't drawn the stairs, walls, seat mountings, safety railing, or windows, but I think they're implicit.

I've assumed 1500mm seat pitching for the big guys with 5m of headroom and 3m of width for wings, 800mm seat pitching for the human sizes (slightly more generous than an airline) with 3m ceiling (eg - room for overhead bins), and 500mm seat pitches for the small guys, with 2m of roof height for them. But that can be changed based on how dense you want to pack people or the exact size of your races

[image]

Your big guys have full car height headroom, your humans have the larger ground floor, and your smalls have the upper floor, and their own hallway, but its wide enough can still overtake in the hallway.

[image]

The car size is 5m wide, 5m high, and 20m long.

[image]

OpenScad Source

```
      color("blue") cube([5000,20000,5]);

      color("aqua") translate([3000,800,3000]) cube([2000,17000,5]);

      for (y = [1000:1500:20000])
      {
        translate([200,y,800]) cube([1500,400,5]);
        
        translate([200,y,700]) cube([1500,10,700]);
      }

      for (y = [1000:800:18000])
      {
        translate([3500,y,400]) cube([1500,400,5]);
        translate([3500,y,300]) cube([1500,10,700]);
      }

      for (y = [1500:500:17500])
      {
        translate([4000,y,3400]) cube([1000,200,5]);
        translate([4000,y,3300]) cube([1000,10,400]);
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend:

**2 rows of chairs** along the walls facing inwards. The middle space should be large (maybe 8 feet across) so the bigger species can move around.

**Different cars for different species** so you can make announcements in the way that is easiest for each species. I assume you have special seats for the species.

Now the only thing is making these cars so they can hold large numbers of people. Since my design is basically a wider train car with less seating the only way to fit more people is to have large terminals and more exits so the trains can be longer.